# Calling Spring controller methods from javascript (ajax) not triggering?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring

Making request from javascript to Spring controller method as follows

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          var xmlHttp
          var xmlHttp
          function show()
          {   
              if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
              {
              xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
               }
              else if (window.ActiveXObject)
              {
                  xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
              if(xmlHttp==null)
              {
                  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                  return;
              }
              var FAC_LICENSE_NO=document.getElementById("FAC_LICENSE_NO").value;
              //var url="/Final/WEB-INF/jsp/SurrenderViews/Ajax.jsp";
              var url="http://localhost:8080/Final/Ajax.FSu";
              url +="?param1="+FAC_LICENSE_NO;
              alert(url);
              xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
              xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
              xmlHttp.send(null);         
            }   
          function stateChange()
          {   
                if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
                {
                    document.getElementById("factoryname").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText
                }
         }
    </script>
```

and my controller

```
public class PhaseTwoFormSurrenderOfLicense extends MultiActionController implements Connections {

     public ModelAndView DataInput(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
     {
         return new ModelAndView("SurrenderViews/DataInput");
     } 
     public String Ajax(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
     {
           System.out.println("Maritammanafvara");
           String returning="<input type=\"text\" style=\"border: none\" name=\"Factory_name\" readonly=\"readonly\" value=\"HIHI\">";
           return returning;

     } 
}
```

and in the above code I am able to call both DataInput and Ajax methods from html anchor tag, but calling from XMLHttpRequest(ajax) object not going.
Can any one tell the region?

Answer (score 1):

can you try 
 `var url="Ajax.FSu";`

instead of

`var url="http://localhost:8080/Final/Ajax.FSu";`

Comment: can you use a browser tool like firebug and see if a request is going

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your `methodNameResolver`, which Spring uses to route URLs to `MultiActionController`'s, it might be something like `PropertiesMethodNameResolver` or one created by yourself. This is my dispatcher:

```
    <bean id="methodNameResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.ParameterMethodNameResolver">
    <property name="paramName" value="method" />
</bean>


<bean class="your.controller">
    <property name="methodNameResolver" ref="methodNameResolver" />
</bean>


public class YourController extends MultiActionController

    public ModelAndView abcdef(...){

    }
}
```

this will map to
url?method=abcdefg

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a library to use for AJAX? jQuery has handy methods for this: api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax("http://localhost:8080/Final/Ajax.FSu").done(function (data) {
    // do stuff with data
}).fail(function () {
    // do stuff when failed
});
```

Also you'd need to encode a proper URL, not hardcode the localhost part there. Spring MVC has a handy tag for this:

```
<spring:url value="Final/Ajax.FSu" />
```

will output the URL for you and

```
<spring:url value="Final/Ajax.FSu" var="yourURL" />
```

will insert the URL in the context variable to use in your jsp files like this:

```
<a href="${yourURL}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thats  answer not related my question sir.

Comment: I just saw this code of handrafted XmlHttpRequest code and immediately thought that you might want to use a library to handle all the quirks for you - I thought this might solve your problem in the process. If this is an unwanted suggestion though, then I stand corrected - sorry.